# Sharepoint Client Object Model update all items in collection

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have some test code that works fine for updating all items in the collection but I've seen tips that say in the majority of cases, as a best practice, you should only have one call to ExecuteQuery(). I'm not sure how to do that, if I remove the first call the code breaks with a collection has not been initialized error. Is there a way to change this code to only have one ExecuteQuery? My code is below. Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("my url to list");
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml="<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='xfoc'/></IsNull></Where></Query></View>";
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++ )
        {
            items[i]["Title"] = "unprocessed record # " + i.ToString();
            items[i].Update();
        }

        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.ReadKey();



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. I believe you misunderstood the best practice. In your example you can't update the item collection without even getting it from the server in first place. So the first ExecuteQuery() is mandatory.

Think ExecuteQuery() as a round trip to the server to fetch data. It has to be used where it is absolutely needed.

Check Best Practice 4 in [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Best-Practices-SharePoint-0c49673e) article.

Comment: Thanks @NLV, that's helpful, and clears up the confusion.